# Using population mean and population std deviation to test range of values

Tags: statistics

Given: population mean μ = 156 and population standard deviation σ = 5.1.

No more than 15% of values should be less than 150. What percent of values are actually less than 150?

This is a homework problem, so you're welcome to hint instead of telling me the answer. I've looked through my notes and can't find anything similar, not for lack of trying

Edit: values are normally distributed

Comment: Hint: if mean and standard deviation are known you can transform into a standard normal variable by taking $Z = \frac{X - \mu}{\sigma}$.

Comment: Thanks @MattDyer...So it would look something like this: $Z = \frac{156-150}{5.1} = 1.17$ then 

normalcdf(-inf, -1.17) = 11.9% chance of being < 150

Comment: Yes, that looks good to me

Comment: @MattDyer...you're my hero